# Get Particular Word in Output using Sql

Tags: sql-server

This is my query.

```
select imgsrc from images where id = 1
```

Output like this,

```
imgsrc

<img src="http://mypage/tiles/imgs/imgfilename.png"/>
```

But I want my output is like  `imagefilename.png` if its possible?

Is it possible then what is the way I follow to get my required output?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replace img src from a Html column in Sql Sqrver](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33778419/11683)

Comment: Why don't you do that in the client application? SQL, the language isn't very good in string manipulation. In this case though you are asking for *HTML parsing*. Even a regex could fail with this one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a UDF which returns the name after matching and finding the patterns.

```
CREATE FUNCTION ufcGetImageName(@imageSrc varchar(200))  
RETURNS varchar(200)   
AS   
BEGIN  
     DECLARE @position INT

     /* here it will fetch the image source followed by any other image attributes*/
     SET @position = CHARINDEX('src="', @imageSrc) + 5           
     SET @imageSrc = SUBSTRING(@imageSrc, @position, LEN(@imageSrc))

     /* here it wil fetch only the image url leaving other image attributes*/
     SET @position = CHARINDEX('"', @imageSrc) 
     SET @imageSrc = SUBSTRING(@imageSrc, 0, @position)

     /* here it will fetch the image name alone */
     SET @position = CHARINDEX('/', reverse(@imageSrc)) 
     SET @imageSrc = SUBSTRING(reverse(@imageSrc), 0, @position)

     RETURN reverse(@imageSrc)
END;
```

And call with any query

```
SELECT 
  imgSrc as imagesrc, 
  dbo.ufcGetImageName(imgSrc) AS imagename 
FROM 
  images;
```

Here is the [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/62e78b/4)